# Unable to link html file to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Unable to get jquery to do its magic, on a live website. I have tried to figure this out for myself but getting nowhere. Its just a case of linking the html and css to the jquery but I am unable to do this. Help appreciated.

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Magic</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-1.4.1-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the stylesheet:

```
div {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And here's the j query magic:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function() {
        $('div').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the jQuery source file in the correct directory? Have you referenced your actual script? Is this working locally?

Comment: It also might be `jquery-1.4.1-min.js` instead of `jQuery-1.4.1-min.js`. Nevertheless, it is very old version of jQuery, you know...

Comment: You may want to check for 404 errors in your browser console.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a problem with the files location.

But if your goal is to make an opacity fade. Try:

```
div{
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the path in your `href` is prbably incorrect. It could also be a spelling or filename case issue.

Learn more about [Absolute and Relative Paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Start a path with:

- `./` or `(no slash)` to start in the current directory.
- `/` to start from the root directory (the highest level you can place your site files).
- `../` to start from the parent directory (up one directory).

From your code this is what your setup is. I have no idea if your file is named `index.html` or if it is in the root directory or not.

> ```
> /index.html
> /jQuery-1.4.1-min.js
> /stylesheet.css
> ```

What paths work here?

- jQuery-1.4.1-min.js
- ./jQuery-1.4.1-min.js
- /jQuery-1.4.1-min.js

Now, if you moved either your index.html file or your jQuery-1.4.1-min.js file, things would not work.

**A**

> ```
> /about/index.html
> /jQuery-1.4.1-min.js
> /stylesheet.css
> ```

What paths work here?

- ../jQuery-1.4.1-min.js - move up and out of `/about/` and look there
- /jQuery-1.4.1-min.js - start at the root, that is, the first `/`

**B**

> ```
> /index.html
> /js/jQuery-1.4.1-min.js
> /stylesheet.css
> ```

What paths work here?

- js/jQuery-1.4.1-min.js - start in current directory, move into `/js/` and look there
- /js/jQuery-1.4.1-min.js - start at the root, that is, the first `/`, move into `/js/` and look there

You can move up multiple directories with multiple `../`.

**C**

> ```
> /path/to/some/folder/index.html
> /js/jQuery-1.4.1-min.js
> /stylesheet.css
> ```

What paths work here?

- ../../../../js/jQuery-1.4.1-min.js - move up and out of `/folder/`, move up and out of `/some/`, move up and out of `/to/`, move up and out of `/path/`, start in current directory and move into `/js/` and look there
- /js/jQuery-1.4.1-min.js - start at the root, that is, the first `/`, move into `/js/` and look there